# При попытке вернуть Response возникает ошибка 500. Понимаю, что не может перейти по url, но как исправить не представляю. Буду благодарен за помощь

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

````
views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TaskCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        authors = Author.objects.all()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = request.data
            author_id = [author.id for author in authors if form.getlist('email')[0] == author.email_author]                    
            if author_id:
                ### Эта часть работает
                return redirect ‘home’
            else:
                context = {
                        'task': form.getlist('task'),
                        'fio': form.getlist('fio')
                        }
            return Response({'context': context})

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('task_add_helpz/', FormView.as_view()),
    path('add_author/', TaskCreateView.as_view()),
]

error:
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/task/add_author/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 412, in finalize_response
    % type(response)
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
[20/Aug/2020 00:04:37] "POST /api/v1/task/add_author/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81970```
````

Comment: расставь правильно отступы в вопросе, а то не совсем понятно как именно у тебя проходят if/else(`if request.method == "POST":`)

Comment: А зачем ты делаешь проверку на метод **POST**? У тебя и так функция **post**, а значит метод будет такой же